# Is there a difference between request().get(url) and request().request(Method.GET,url)

Tags: rest-assured

I want to know if there is any difference between request().get(url) and request().request(Method.GET,url) in RestAssured.

When I try to do get() both seem to working same.

Comment: What library is it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @alec_djinn The library is io.restassured.specification.*;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, functionally they are the same, it's a matter of style. Both call the private method

```java
applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(String method, String path, Object... unnamedPathParams)
```

You can choose one to match your code style.

Comment: @Sandy please mark as correct answer or upvote if it's helpful.